# How to login on proxy sites?

Tags: proxy, http-proxy, proxy-server

I am using this proxy site: http://svnit786.appspot.com but when I try to login to any site it shows an error. I have tried http://fitdeal.de but I'm unable to login. What should I do now?

Comment: These probably do not support form submission. There are proxies that support it but require subscription. You can try hidemyass.com where you can also set proxy server from advanced options found below URL address.

Comment: hidemyass is also blocked here.

Comment: What website are you trying to login to?

Comment: I am trying to login https://put.io

Comment: I tried to login from HMA Amsterdam server but clicking on "Login" button did not do anything. I think since login button is JavaScript, HMA proxy does not handle such script well, at least public free proxy, although in advanced options there is an option to disable it if checked.

Comment: I would really advise to use a proxy configuration settings within your browser. If you find fast proxy server it will perform a lot better than other popular proxy sites.

Comment: As of 2020, this question is totally useless, because both links are dead and the question does not provide anything useful beside.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using Chrome or Firefox I strongly recommend you install the addon/extension called Media Hint. Once installed there are no configuration changes to be made, as the extension will automatically change proxy according to the website that you visit.

https://www.mediahint.com/

Alternatively I have had alot of success with the application Spotflux:

http://www.spotflux.com/

Alternatively if you are prepared to pay then I would recommend **Identity Cloaker** They offer a free demo it's fully functional and there is no time restriction on how long you can evaluate the software. However, when the demo mode is enabled, it is possible to visit just a few domains/websites.

http://www.identitycloaker.com/cms/home

Comment: spotflux is too slow

Comment: @Captcha How was Mediahint ?

Comment: not workes so well.unable to unblock sites.